# Multiple View Models for one POST action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

Is it possible to use the same post action, but with two different models, with the model to use decided by the role of the current user?  I've simplified greatly my real scenario into the example below, but the idea is that I have two roles: Manager and Regional.  Manager can add a record (let's just say it's a User in this example) with only first and last name.  Regional on the other hand can do the same as a manager but must also add multiple other pieces of information stored on nested view models and value type properties with required, among other, data annotations.

I would like to use these separate view models and views so that I don't have to do null checks or conditional required properties based on the role.  Also, as Stephen pointed out below, a second/differently named action method works too but was just curious if the route could stay the same (Users/Add) somehow.

Here's what I've tried:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Regional"))
        return View("AddRegional", new AddRegionalViewModel());

    return View("Add", new AddViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(AddViewModel addViewModel)
{
    // process manager add command

    return RedirectToAction("List");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(AddRegionalViewModel addRegionalViewModel)
{
    // process regional add command

    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

**View Models**

```
public class AddViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string First { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

public class AddRegionalViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string First { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Last { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // in reality there are a LOT more value types / nested view models here
}
```

**Views**

*Add.cshtml*

```
@model ModelBindingHell.ViewModels.AddViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

<h2>Add</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

*AddRegional.cshtml*

```
@model ModelBindingHell.ViewModels.AddRegionalViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

<h2>Add</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Not without creating a custom model binder and writing a lot of code to determine which model to initialize and bind. Why not simply have 2 post methods - `public ActionResult AddViewModel(AddViewModel addViewModel)` and `public ActionResult AddRegionalViewModel(AddRegionalViewModel addRegionalViewModel)`?

Comment: I was hoping to keep the route /Users/Add and not have to have /Users/AddRegional as well.

Comment: The action name is defined by the `HttpGet`, not by the `HttpPost`

Comment: No need to change any routes. The GET method remains the same.

Comment: I'm probably just nitpicking/being a perfectionist here, but what I meant was the post would have to go to /Users/AddRegional instead of /Users/Add.

Comment: You could contain one model inside the other giving you two models.  Either one or both are set dependent on the user role.  The view then simply hides part of the view if null, or shows both if not null. Of course it would all have to start with either a Get or a login right?

Comment: John Peters - That's definitely one way to do it.  I think I'll just concede to Stephen's notion of two differently named POST actions.  Stephen if you add that as an answer I will accept it.  Seems like it's the least amount of work necessary and makes the most sense.